# How to install Wine 4.13 (unmet dependencies libfaudio0)?

Tags: apt, wine, dependencies

I am currently using Ubuntu 19.04, but this has been a problem with previous versions of Ubuntu, including 18.04 LTS. When attempting to install Wine from the [WineHQ repositories](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu), I get an unmet dependencies error for libfaudio0. What can I do to install a newer version of Wine than is available in the Ubuntu repositories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known problem with versions of Wine > 4.5 for Ubuntu 18.04, 18.10, and 19.04. It occurs because libfaudio0 is not yet available in the official repositories. The package *is* expected to be included in Ubuntu 19.10.

You may obtain the libfaudio0 from the following locations:

- [Ubuntu 19.10](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/faudio) (Eoan)
- [Launchpad PPA](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=faudio)
- Open Build Service (see [WineHQ discussion](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=32192) for details)

Download `deb` files for *both* i386 and amd64. Install them using `dpkg -i libfaudio*.deb`. You should now be able to install Wine from the WineHQ repository.